# Connecting RStudio with remote mysql database

Tags: mysql, rstudio

The data from my mysql database are:

> user: root
>
> password: query
>
> dbname: bd_test
>
> host: 127.0.0.1
>
> port: 3306

I´m using RStudio, I want to have access locally from another computer. The adress IP of my msql server is: 192.X.X.X

When I run to RStudio, I do the following steps and the following error is displayed:

> install.packages("RMySQL")
>
> library("RMySQL")
>
> mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(),user='root',password='query',dbname='bd_test',
>    host='192.X.X.X')
>
> Failed to connect to database: Error: Host 'MYHost-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

I added new rules (port) to the firewall window but still not working.
Where is the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Permits must be enabled in your MySQL server.In your Mysql server console put the next commands (Windows 7):

> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin" mysql –u root -p
>
> mysql>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  *.* TO 'namehost-PC'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY
>   'Password'WITH GRANT OPTION ;
>
> mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGIES